# Win form gradient background and resize c#

Tags: c#, winforms

i set a form back color gradient and code works fine but the problem is when i re-size then huge flickering occur. so guide me how can i minimize flickering when form have gradient back color. here is my code thanks.

```
private void myform_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle,
                                                               Color.WhiteSmoke,
                                                               Color.SteelBlue,
                                                               90F))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
            }
        }

        private void myform_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invalidate();
        }
```

Comment: Try settings DoubleBuffered property 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered.aspx'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double buffering:

```
public myform() // Form constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DoubleBuffered = true;
}
```

Comment: when i am show a form with gradient background and form border style none then flicker occur. i set the DoubleBuffered = true; but still flicker occur. can u guide me how to stop this flickering in case of border less form. thanks

Comment: 1. Use a bitmap with a gradient as form background. (or) 2. Place a custom control painting the gradient on the form and set its docking property to `Fill`.